# Smartsheet api workspace sheet set

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

Thi is my first question.
I'm developing an exportation from our SQL based ERP to smartsheep.
We are developing in .NET (VB).
I'm creating / uploading sheet and creating data in row without problems.
My actual and almost last trouble is to be able to set a specified workspace...

Example.
I Upload a template XLSX file to smartsheet. I populate it with all the data i need to put inside, than (and here we are) i would like to set to the uploaded Sheet a specific workspace...

I'm using nuget smartsheet-csharp-sdk Version 2.126.0

Thank you for any reply.

This is more or less my code:
Dim smartsheet As SmartsheetClient = New SmartsheetBuilder().Build()
Dim sheet As Sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.ImportXlsSheet(Dim XLSFILENAME as string, Nothing, 0, Nothing)

Than i have my build / upload rows code...

but no idea on how to set the workspace....

Answer (score 0):

With the import ImportXlsSheet you can't set a destination, the sheet will be created at the root (home) or smartsheet.
You've to create the sheet, and by the response you should have access to the sheetId created.

With a second call to the API, move the sheet to the specific workspace. see also : https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#move-sheet